# Ion-tabs and hide-nav-bar leaves space, with top 0px also

Tags: css, ionic-framework

I wanted to hide the nav-bar on a view within tabs(`ion-tab`)

Have tried `top:0` on `.tabs` also and `hide-nav-bar also`

Apparently in `ion-view` if i use `hide-nav-bar` it leaves space befor the tabs and making it to top:0px (`.tabs { top: 0 !important; }`) leaves space between content and tabs

see image below

When using `hide-nav-bar` on ion-view:

[image]

With `.tabs { top: 0 !important; }`:

[image]

However , nav bar hides on tabs bottom and there is no space when it on bottom, is there any solution to hide nav-bar without leaving any space

Comment: does you ion-content have the class 'has-header' or 'padding'?

Comment: no,this has now been solved :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved now, wanted to share this

This was because of the .has-tabs-top class that was being added to the ion-content element.

added this along with `hide-nav-bar` in view and  `.tabs { top: 0 !important; }`

```
.has-tabs-top {
  top: 49px !important; /*  height of the tabs */
}
```